# Defining Layout Sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout, layoutparams

I want to make such a `layout` that basically will have 2 `columns`. There'll be `TextView` and `Editext` on the same `row`. But what I want is to set some Fixed size or weight to each `column`. I know I can set weights to `TextView` and `EditText` but I don't want to set weights everytime I add a row.

When I add some new `rows`, I want `views` inside that `row` to be aligned without setting some fixed sizes to each of them. But I don't know how to do it.

If there will be more questions about my problem please ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem with android:weight ?

Comment: I don't want to set weights to each view in the row

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it in java code.
infliate your layout and set weights to only which you want and leave others.

Good Luck...